# Selenium: wait for server response just long enough?

Tags: selenium

We have *large* suites of selenium scripts and some of the tests are "unstable": On the CI-builds they fail but on the dev-machines they are ok.

We assume that the reason is in performance: the CI-builds are slower than the dev-machines and our application blocks any interaction with the web-app directly after an action until the server response comes back.

This brings me to the question:

**How can the client know how long the server might take?**

We can wait after each click for a long time -> but this will slow down the test-suite heavily.

Is there a trick to wait **just long enough** ?

Since our suites are so large, I do not want to maintain/treat this in each and every test-case but generically in test-framework or on server side.

I dont have much technical experience with selenium, but this sounds more like a conceptual problem.

Comment: How are you implementing your waiting statements?

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, waitTimeout);
    wait.until(expectedCondition);

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, and I'd suggest your best bet is a long timeout to allow for the server to take a long time to respond.

Comment: I posted a solution, please upvote/accept if useful @Bastl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you can do (at a high level).

On the client you can call your API. When the API completes (whether success or fail) you can set a global variable stating that the API has completed.

```
$.getJSON('/some/endpoint.xhtml', {
  someParam: someVar
})
.done(function (data) {
    // do work
})
.fail(function (data) {
  // do error handling
})
.always(function(data) {
    // window.testVars will need to be initialized earlier
    // like so : window.testVars = { completedEndoint = 0 };
    window.testVars.completedEndpoint++;
});
```

Then in the Java Selenium code you have access to those variables through a `JavascriptExecutor` driver.

```
private static Map<String, Object> getState(WebDriver driver)
{
    Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String,Object>)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return window.testVars");
    return map;
}
```

Then in your test you can use:

```
Map<String,Object> defState = initializeState(driver);
performUseCaseToCallTheEndpoint();

ExpectedCondition<Boolean> condition = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>()
{
  @Override
  public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver)
  {
      Map<String,Object> curState = getState(driver);
      if(curState.get("completedEndpoint") > defState get("completedEndpoint"))
      {
           return true;
      }
      else
      {
          return false;
      }
  }
};
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60); 
wait.until(condition);
```

This should get you started.

Answer (score -1):

In the class, you could have fields

```
public int startTime;
public int stopTime;
public int averageResponseTime = 2000;
```

Here, set `averageResponseTime` to the maximum time you are willing to wait for a response (in this example, 2000 milliseconds)

In your @Before/testSetup method:

```
// set the startime for the test    
startTime = new Date();
```

In your @After/tearDown method:

```
// set the stopTime
stopTime = new Date();

// calculate how long it took
int duration = stopTime - startTime;

// average out the response time
averageResponseTime  = (averageResponseTime + duration)/2;
```

In your test, instantiate a new wait, passing in `averageResponseTime`  as the waitTimeout

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, averageResponseTime); wait.until(expectedCondition);
```

After the first test (or so) the timeout will get closer and closer to the average time the server actually takes to respond.

Comment: Nice, but we would need to persist the average time over different builds.

Comment: Do you have a requirement to not store any persistent data? 
Actually, it might make sense to just start a new average with each build. If your server's response times can vary as you say, the average from a previous build might not be relevant to a future build.

Comment: Down-voter, please comment to explain how my answer could be improved, BEFORE down-voting. Also might want to review SO's down-voting guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down thanks.